# Facebook api returns Catchable fatal error while retriveing posts from group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all post from a group using facebook graph api using the sample code provided in documentation.

```
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
  $accessToken,
  'GET',
  '/1051892924832742'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
echo '<pre>';
  print_r($graphgraphObject);
  echo '</pre>';
```

But i will get the floowing exception in my code

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Facebook\FacebookApp, string given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newfacebookapi\profile.php on line 63 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newfacebookapi\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 97

**UPDATE**

I have modified the above code to this ,now the error message is gone,but didn't get the result.

```
     $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXX',
  'app_secret' => '6XXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

       $response = $fb->get('/1051892924832742', $accessToken);
       $graph = $response->getGraphObject();
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($graph);
      echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the output from the above

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chat World
            [privacy] => CLOSED
            [id] => 1051892924832742
        )

)
```

Gives only group name,id and privacy

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate fields, which you want to get:
Something like that:

```
$response = $fb->get(
     '/1051892924832742?fields=id,name,email,owner',
     $accessToken
);
```